# How Can I display Specific User Pages?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WooCommerce website and it provides some sort of Services.

Let's say I sell Custom Videos (Example) and A user buys 10 videos from me. Now I can host it somewhere else (the file link) but I want to give a user personal/private page where the person can check out all his orders from.

In short: I want user specific pages.

For now I used Password Protected pages but with over 25 orders pending its very difficult to manually create each page.

I tried: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-private-content-plus/ but it keeps asking to to buy the pro version and is really annoying.

What is the best way I can show people their order products?

Comment: Do you need to show specific pages to all members ?

Comment: No Per User. Like "Page 1" to "Username: user1"

"Page 2" to "Username: user2"